# Calling a Java function from C#.Net

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, integration

I just want to call a java function from ASP.Net... Please guide me !!!

I have seen JNBridge but its not free... :(

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: The link points to calling c# in java program. (?)

Comment: Sorry about that. Wrong question interpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible options that i can think of :-

1. Expose the java function's functionality through a service (Recommended - Loosely Coupled)
2. Integrate through backend eg: database. Both programs can access a common database and pass data through here. (Not Highly Recommented - Very Tightly Coupled)
3. Use an open source bridge eg : [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/)

Note:  I have not used this bridge ever but it seems to be something similar to what you are looking for. [Refer their sample here](http://code.google.com/p/jni4net/source/browse/trunk/content/samples/helloWorldFromCLR/Program.cs#)

Comment: Thanks InSane, i am studying jni4net and will update you if i get an face any issue.

Comment: ya you are right ... there are lots of encryption algorithms but project.net (java provided open source) has its own function to encrypt provided password ... to make things in sync i want that function in my C# website...

Comment: @xtremist - I would go with my first option if i were you. As i understand it, you can very easily create a web service wrapper and expose the necessary function from project.net. Then you can just call this service from your .NET code. That would still be my preferred way over using a bridge!!

Comment: yes i am doing this through service ... Thanks to guide me InSane.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for, but you could check out [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/uses.html).

Answer (score 1):

and why you wanna do that?

1- It will slow your code also as Plateform Conversion came into picture

2- It will make your code hard to test.

3- It will make your code hard to understand.

There must be very solid reason because what ever you can do with Java , you can do in C#

if possible you can always COPY & PASTE same function in ASP.Net application

Comment: if it's just one function, sure, port it, but if it's a big thing... porting isn't always feasible.

Comment: ya you are right.. but i am using java's open source project.net (integration project.net in my website) !!! they have a password encryption function and in order to do single sign on i have to do the same encryption in my website.

Comment: getting code from java and convert it in to C# is simple but what if they (project.net community) changed its encryption logic (as it is a open source) in future ... :( for that i have to always check project.net updates..